# Update post/row, instead of creating new one

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am building a system, where you can create blog posts for your website.
In there I have an ajax-function which is saving a draft of your post every two minutes.
In this way you're not losing your work if your computer or internet crashes.

But right now, it is saving a new row every time it auto-saves. How to I do, so instead of creating multiple rows, it is updating the row instead?

I have already tried with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which didn't work. I think it might be because that it requires an unique field in the form. But the only unique in my database is the actual ID of the post/row.

This is the code I tried:

```
INSERT INTO blog (title, text, date) 
VALUES ('$blog_title','$blog_text','".time()."')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
title='$blog_title', text='$blog_text', modified_date='".time()."'
```

I have an idea, to get the post/row ID, when the post is auto-saved the first time. Here I could use `mysql_insert_id()`. Then this ID could be stored in a hidden input field and when it auto-saves again, it will see that there already is a post/row with that ID, and then it will just update instead of creating a new one.

Is that a good and safe solution, or should I do something else?

I can't seem to find a better one.

---

I have found some other similar questions, but they where using JSON, which I haven't worked with yet.

Hope someone can help me with this :)

Comment: Use the hidden field as you suggest. But if it's filled in, you can just do an `UPDATE`, don't bother with `INSERT` because you know it will be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new row, put the ID into a hidden field. Then the code to process the input can do:

```
if ($_POST['id']) {
    // update existing row
} else {
    // insert new row and put ID into hidden field
}
```

There's no need to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` because you know from the input data whether it's indended as a new entry or an update.

Comment: But in my code a text also displays when the draft was saved. In the bottom it says: Draft saved at 10:01pm (according to the date of the post), so how to I put the ID in the hidden field? I can only show one  ajax result at once.